# Sending user input words through keystrokes in C#

Tags: c#, keystroke

I'm trying to take a string from a textbox that a user inputs into and have a keystroke for each char in that string.

```
SendKeys.Send("{SHIFT}{ENTER} " + text);
```

This does not work, I also tried to run a for loop to output each char but couldn't really get it to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "does not work"?

Answer (score 1):

the correct syntax for sending Shift+Enter is:

```
SendKeys.Send("+{ENTER}");
```

I think you should try:

```
foreach(var i in text)
   SendKeys.Send("+{ENTER}("+i+")");
```

Note that I can not understand why you are trying to press 3 keys simultaneously. If you are trying to send shift+enter and then a char:

```
foreach(var i in text)
   SendKeys.Send("+{ENTER}{"+i+"}");
```

Comment: it's for a game and shift+enter is a key combination I need to type before doing the required keystrokes i need